# How to pass information out of firestore transaction in golang SDK?

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

I'd like to pass information out of firestore transaction in golang.

This is documented here [[src-java]](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/transactions#java_1).

If we look e.g. at java code, it looks like this:

```java
final DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
ApiFuture<String> futureTransaction = db.runTransaction(transaction -> {
  DocumentSnapshot snapshot = transaction.get(docRef).get();
  Long newPopulation = snapshot.getLong("population") + 1;
  if (newPopulation <= 1000000L) {
    transaction.update(docRef, "population", newPopulation);
    return "Population increased to " + newPopulation;
  } else {
    throw new Exception("Sorry! Population is too big.");
  }
});
System.out.println(futureTransaction.get());   // [me] <-- this is a  future, so it can return both a value and an error
ManageDataSnippets.java
```

On the other hand the go code looks like this [[src-go]](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/transactions#go_1):

```golang
ref := client.Collection("cities").Doc("SF")

// ↓↓↓ [me] only `err` is returned here, no "positive" value
err := client.RunTransaction(ctx, func(ctx context.Context, tx *firestore.Transaction) error {
        doc, err := tx.Get(ref)
        if err != nil {
                return err
        }
        pop, err := doc.DataAt("population")
        if err != nil {
                return err
        }
        newpop := pop.(int64) + 1
        if newpop <= 1000000 {
                return tx.Set(ref, map[string]interface{}{
                        "population": pop.(int64) + 1,
                }, firestore.MergeAll)
        }
        return errors.New("population is too big")
})
if err != nil {
        log.Printf("An error has occurred: %s", err)
}
```

Is it possible to return a value from firestore transaction in golang, or is the go SDK missing this feature? I eyeballed the other languages, like python, swift, js and looks like they also allow to return a "positive" value from the transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a variable in an outer scope. Assign to the variable in the transaction.

```
var newpop int64  // <-- declaration

err := client.RunTransaction(ctx, func(ctx context.Context, tx *firestore.Transaction) error {
        doc, err := tx.Get(ref)
        if err != nil {
                return err
        }
        pop, err := doc.DataAt("population")
        if err != nil {
                return err
        }
        newpop = pop.(int64) + 1 // <-- short var decl changed to assignment
        if newpop <= 1000000 {
                return tx.Set(ref, map[string]interface{}{
                        "population": newpop,
                }, firestore.MergeAll)
        }
        return errors.New("population is too big")
})
if err != nil {
        log.Printf("An error has occurred: %s", err)
}

log.Print("the new pop is", newpop)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Is it really that simple  I wonder why the other langs use _on success_ callbacks, but maybe this is because they use async constructs and go code is sync (at the `if err != nil` block we're sure the transactions was commited or rejected). Anyways, will try this tomorrow and accept the answer. Welcome to SO :)

Comment: Google's example has "to pass information out of transactions" but it doesn't actually pass any information out. That's how I got to SO but I'm still not convinced what's the best way. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#passing_information_out_of_transactions